# Get the number of followers of an instagram account without using api

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

I am trying to get the number of followers of an instagram account with this:

```
<?php 
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1");
if ($response !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data !== null) {
        $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edgeedge_followed_by_follow']['count'];
        $followedBy = $data['graphql']['user']['']['count'];
        echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
    }
}
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work because the variable $data is null, so this condition is false:

```
if ($data !== null) {
        $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edgeedge_followed_by_follow']['count'];
        $followedBy = $data['graphql']['user']['']['count'];
        echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: I've tried your code, `$data` wasn't `null`, but I got a bunch of notices about trying to access undefined indices, so it seems you didn't get the right structure.

Comment: The `edgeedge_followed_by_follow` index seems to be the culprit. I'm guessing you accidentally inserted the correct index inside a wrong one, instead of replacing it. And then you left the lower index empty (where `edge_follow` should be).

Comment: And after several tries, I got `null` in `$data`. When I visit the page, it asks me to log in. So I guess the access is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your $response is not `JSON`, it returns `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

they disabled these legacy APIs , see http://instagram.com/developer